# Inequality regarding a function and its Fourier transform

Tags: analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

Does a continuous compactly supported function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfy the inequality
$$\lvert f(x)\rvert+\lvert \widehat{f}(x)\rvert \leq C(1+\lvert x\rvert)^{-1-\epsilon},\quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$
for some $C,\epsilon >0$ ?

Here, $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. Presumably everything is defined since $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

**Edit 1**:

For any $\epsilon >0\,$ I can bound $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leq \max \left(1,\frac{\Vert f\Vert_\infty}{\min_K \left(1+\lvert x \rvert\right)^{-1-\epsilon}}\right)$, then I want to use the following (but my function is just $\mathcal{C}^0$...)

**Theorem (Paley-Wiener)**
If $f \in \mathcal{C}_o^\infty$ and $f(z)=0$ for $ \lvert z \rvert > R$, then
$$\lvert \widehat{f}(z) \rvert \leq C_n(1+ \lvert z\rvert)^{-n}e^{2\pi\lvert \text{Im}(z)\rvert R} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+.$$

I am referring to what they say in page 4 of the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X19309813

Comment: You surely have tested your conjecture on examples ? Could you show some of them ?

Comment: I've tested it on bump functions and then tried proving it (Edit1).